# Ionic 4 popover and/or actionsheet on PWA?

Tags: drop-down-menu, progressive-web-apps, ionic4

I'm building an Ionic 4 PWA and I am looking for a "simple" solution to the following:

For each item in a list e.g. a newsfeed or comments list: I want a "more" icon (the dotdotdot icon) to show a list of options the logged in user has available e.g. if they own the comment or newsfeed item they will have extra options like "edit" and "delete" etc.

Now I can use an ActionSheet to show these options and dynamically add the correct options into the sheet - all well and good. But this only looks good on a mobile device. If the user is on a desktop then an action sheet looks out of place. So, a Popover would look better but only on the desktop view.

Is it possible to dynamically create a popover in code without having to create a component for it as the items in the popover list will vary depending on what type of object it is e.g. newsfeed, comment etc and their access rights to that object e.g. edit/delete etc.

Not sure if I have explained this very well but looking for a slick, simple UI Ionic 4 way of displaying "options" to the user when then click/tap on the more icon depending on device.

I did go down the route of having ActionSheet for mobile users and Material Design Mat-Menu for the desktop but it just seems over complicated.

Any advice would help.

Thanks,

Rowie

Answer (score 0):

How about a popover with a custom css class that is using a screen media query?